# Laraveldaily CRUD example throws error: cannot find module '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, crud

Trying to implement the CRUD example with Laravel and vue3  from
[https://laraveldaily.com/post/laravel-8-vue-3-crud-composition-api](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

the step **npm run dev** throws

> failed to load config from F:_MYDATA\ProjectsLaravel\nuky\vite.config.js
> error when starting dev server:
> Error: Cannot find module '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

The vite.config.js looks like:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        })

    ],
});
```

Seemingly the error is in the config file itself. Anyway, I tried restarting VSC, TS server and executing a npm i -D @types/node
Also tried:  npm i @vuejs/plugin-vue

Nothing helped.

Comment: Try npm install @vitejs/plugin-vue

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because the module `@vitejs/plugin-vue` is not installed. Look inside your project files to see if the folder `node_modules/@vitejs` exists. I had this problem while using Laravel and Jetstream, I reinstalled Jetstream using `php artisan jetstream:install inertia` and the module was part of the intalls. You can also run `npm install @vitejs/plugin-vue` to install the module.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing the vuejs package.

`npm i vue`